# Different page numbering in appendices while keeping main numbering

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I need to use separate page numbering in appendices while keeping the main numbering. I.e., when the page is in appendix, the header must be like "Appendix 1. Page X of XXX" where XXX is the number of pages in appendix. And in the footer the numbering must be uniform from the first page of the document to the end. How can I do it?

Comment: You need to create a new counter and increment it in the header or using the everypage package.  You can print the last counter value using `\ref{lastpage}` (for example) and use `\AtEndDocument{\addtocounter{mypage}{-1}\refstepcounter{mypage}\label{lastpage}}`

Comment: Please explain. I don't know TeX/LaTeX so good.

Comment: I suppose you want me to create an MWE for you as well.  Sigh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I assume you are using `oneside`.

Note, since not every page has a header, I increment `mypage` using `everypage`, which runs after the page is complete but before the header is added.  Also, `\AtEndDocument` runs before the last `everypage`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcounter{mypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\stepcounter{mypage}}% before header
\AtEndDocument{\refstepcounter{mypage}\label{lastpage}\addtocounter{mypage}{-1}}

\makeatletter% create \pagestyle{appemdix}
\def\ps@appendix{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \let\@evenfoot=\@oddfoot
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil Page \themypage{} of \ref{lastpage}}%
    \let\@evenhead=\@oddhead
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Yada yada yada}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage% push out last page before appendix
\appendix
\setcounter{mypage}{0}%
\pagestyle{appendix}%
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```